# Links are behind video background

Tags: html, css

My links are not showing up, looks like they´re behind my video background. How do I make them appear in front of it?

this is my code:

```
<body>
<header class="v-header container">
<div class="fullscreen-video-wrap">
<video src="video.mp4" autoplay="true" loop="true" muted>. 
</video>
</div>
<div class="header-overlay"></div>
<div class="header-content">
<h1>PÖBEL</h1>
</div>
</header>
<div class="instagram">
<a href="https://www.instagram.com">INSTAGRAM</a></div>
<div class="facebook">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com">FACEBOOK</a>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: fixed it, links still show up behind the video though

Comment: You need to demonstrate this with your CSS

Answer (score -1):

```
<pre>
<header class="v-header container">
<div class="fullscreen-video-wrap">
<video src="BigBuckBunny.mp4" autoplay="false" loop="false" muted></video>
</div>
<div class="header-overlay"></div>`enter code here`
<div class="header-content">
<h1>PÖBEL</h1>
</div>

<div class="instagram"></div>
<ul>
<a href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank">INSTAGRAM</a>
</ul>
<ul>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com">FACEBOOK</a>
</ul>
</header>
</pre>

Use Above code
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to work on your HTML structure. Download a free HTML template and check how they structure their framework.

```
<body>
<head>
<title>Your site/page name</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header-overlay">
    <div class="header-content">
        <h1>PÖBEL</h1>
        <div class="facebook">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank">Instagram</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">FACEBOOK">Facebook</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

If you want to add the video as an overlay then I suggest using CSS to do that.

Comment: i tried that by using z-index but i cant figure out what im doing wrong. what would you suggest